# sign the message and verify with recover message by Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I write the following code for signing the message and then verify it, in java by Bouncy Castle.
signing work properly but verifying not work. the result of code print:
signature tampered
can not recover
and return null.
why eng.hasFullMessage() function return false and why the following code doesn't work?
thanks all.

```java
 
public static String sigVer(PublicKey pu, PrivateKey pr, String original) throws Exception{
        //sign
        BigInteger big = ((RSAKey) pu).getModulus();

        byte[] text = original.getBytes();

        RSAKeyParameters rsaPriv = new RSAKeyParameters(true, big,((RSAPrivateKey) pr).getPrivateExponent());
        RSAKeyParameters rsaPublic = new RSAKeyParameters(false, big,((RSAPublicKey) pu).getPublicExponent());
        RSAEngine rsa = new RSAEngine();
        byte[] data;
        Digest dig = new SHA1Digest();
        ISO9796d2Signer eng = new ISO9796d2Signer(rsa, dig, true);
        eng.init(true, rsaPriv);
        eng.update(text[0]);
        eng.update(text, 1, text.length - 1);

        data = eng.generateSignature();
        String signature = data.toString();
        //verify
        eng = new ISO9796d2Signer(rsa, dig, true);
        eng.init(false, rsaPublic);
        text = signature.getBytes(); 
        if (!eng.verifySignature(text)) {
            System.out.println("signature tampered");
        }
        try{
            if (eng.hasFullMessage()) {
                eng.updateWithRecoveredMessage(signature.getBytes());

            }
                byte[] message = eng.getRecoveredMessage();
                String ss = message.toString();
                return ss;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("can not recover");
            return null;

        }
```

}

Comment: You have Java problems, not crypto problems.`String.getBytes()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Oh, yes. Very very thanks. My problem resolved. In fact .toString() Method doesn't do the conversion that i think. Instead of it, I use new String(byte[] b).

Comment: May I make an additional suggestion? Always explicitly specify the character encoding. In most cases "UTF-8" is correct choice. So instead of `byte[] text = original.getBytes();` you use `byte[] text = original.getBytes("UTF-8");`. And instead of `new String(byte [])` you would use `new String(byte[], "UTF-8");`

Comment: thanks. I have other problem too, when the length of input text for sign becomes large the verify can not do complete. How should this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Actually to verify large messages you have to provide the input for verification which is the original message and not only the signature which works only for full recovery

```
//verify
eng = new ISO9796d2Signer(rsa, dig, true);
eng.init(false, rsaPublic);

// when verifying there has to be also the original plain text
eng.update(text,0,text.length);

signBytes = signature.getBytes(); 
if (!eng.verifySignature(signBytes)) {
     System.out.println("signature tampered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this method and also receive the errors. In addition the "update" method mentioned does not work and the "updateWithRecoveredMessage" does not exist.

After some testing I figured that:

- I have to sue getBytes("UTF-8") and String s = new String(message, "UTF-8")
- I can use up to 234 bytes in the signature, with 235 it will break. (guess it would be 256 bytes but some are used for padding/markers)

If I understand correctly the problem is that the signer only allows a certain amount of bytes to be included in the signature.

If you use a longer payload you MUST include the payload in the verification step as well:

```
    eng.init(false, rsaPublic);
    byte[] message = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
    eng.update(message, 0, message.length);
```

then verification works just fine and you get the first part of the payload with eng.getRecoveredMessage().

For me this defeated the purpose, so I went another way.

The workaround I use is to two a two-step approach:

1) I generate a short key which is stored in the signature
2) use a symmetric (i.e. AES) to encrypt the large payload. I also generate a hash for the payload.
3) the key and hash for the payload is the one included in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times we don't have the original message to update and verifiy by the signature. On the other hand the length is limited to 234 bytes.